# Facebook information attachment issue

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I worked on app where I was sharing information using FBConnect. I was sharing title, description, URL and Image which was working fine before some days ago but suddenly I am getting issue while sharing data

**ERROR; This endpoint has been deprecated .To temporarily reenable it ,you may disable the "augest_2012" platform migration. it will be disable permanently on August 1,2012**

can any please help me on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Same Problem here! I use ShareKit (old version). I would prefer to stick to the old version, because it opens this fancy view in my view. The new version is switching to the app or the webpage! REALLY BIG DISLIKE (guess its a FB fault)!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's not a answer! but I got this error while implementing  [this](http://code.google.com/r/hrl5000-production-clone/source/browse/sample/src/com/codecarpet/fbconnect/sample/MainActivity.java) on Android app facebook integration